# "The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye" on EC2 with RDS

Tags: mysql, maven, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I'm running jenkins on an AWS EC2 server, accessing a mysql DB on AWS RDS.
When running mvn clean install locally it's all good, but when jenkins does it on the EC2 server i get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project plenty: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Plenty-api/workspace/plenty && /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -jar /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Plenty-api/workspace/plenty/target/surefire/surefirebooter9140193949835996613.jar /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Plenty-api/workspace/plenty/target/surefire/surefire21120104041831905tmp /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Plenty-api/workspace/plenty/target/surefire/surefire_08001606298289854825tmp
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Oh yeah that one scales from EasyPeasyException (the call to `System.exit();` by one of your testclasses) to the complete DeepShitException (I had it once locally, reinstalled the VM and everything was good afterwards).

If it is not one of your testclasses (or dependencies of those) calling a `System.exit()` you will have to find the dumps of the VM crash and add them to the question for further assistance (I unfortunately wont be able to handle whatever is stored in such dump files - but finding a solution is oftenly teamwork :)).

This is also documented in the plugins documentation: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/faq.html#vm-termination

Comment: i think i founf the reason: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000f4d82000, 52944896, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 52944896 bytes for committing reserved memory.